# Recursive type definition in flow

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to use flow 0.53.1. Could you please help me explain this weird behavior?

This code sample:

```
/* @flow */

type AnySupportedType =
  | AnySupportedPrimitive
  | AnySupportedObject
  | AnySupportedArray;
type AnySupportedArray = Array<AnySupportedType>;
type AnySupportedObject = { [string]: AnySupportedType };
type AnySupportedPrimitive = boolean | number | string | void;

type DataID = string
type Data = {
  id: DataID
}

const y: Data = { id: "123" }
const x: AnySupportedType = y;
```

Renders this error:

```
17: const x: AnySupportedType = y;
                                ^ object type. This type is incompatible with
17: const x: AnySupportedType = y;
             ^ union: AnySupportedPrimitive | AnySupportedObject | AnySupportedArray
```

[Link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAdlgMoCuOOcAThngCYAquBAvKmGAD5GmVqdBowAKtAJYBbCRgkA3PF179yVGvSYB5AEYArPAGMMyviTVDNjQrVoBDLAG5MbVYI0ib9rGHZFbDgA85u7CTKz4AHzO2Phu6mGMugbGvmAA3mAA2gDOGJLEAOYAugBc8ZYiEQQAvjGuIQlW4tKyChxgOnBwMHh2xCrEFFI6eLQqeQWFKvJwEozOLnEAInYYdgCSy2mTEkVLBKvraenK8+VHm8uoNeiGcMR5YFgXa3YnYOdgAEQAjABMAGZvmBbvdHhgwAAPcqNSrhVx+JxAA) to flow.org web-based example to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Flow has two ways to type Objects. One, your `AnySupportedObject`, treats the object as as dictionary where you can find an item by any key (similar to `Map<string, whatever>`.

The other way is as a record, where there are a specific set of known keys and each key can point to its own type of value (for example, `{a: number, b: string}`.

Those two types have very different meanings, though often either one can apply to a specific object. The type system keeps them distinct and forces you to treat an object in one way or the other to avoid generating type errors.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. I guess I should explicitly convert type for my data object at some point when passing it as `AnySupportedObject `, as I know those types should be compatible. Would be great if Flow provided a way to check the correctness of such explicit transformation though, which it seems to lack now.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Flow does support subtyping relationships between record-style objects and map-style objects. The issue here is actually mutability. I left an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this has to do with mutability. Flow cannot allow this code, since you could write `x.id = 5` (after the appropriate type refinements), since the `AnySupportedType` type allows you to set any supported type, including a `number` as a property.

To solve this, you need to make the object properties covariant, effectively making them read-only:

`type AnySupportedObject = { +[string]: AnySupportedType };`

Note the addition of the `+`.

Once you do this, Flow allows the original assignment but prevents you from setting properties on `x`.

Check out the complete example on [try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAdlgMoCuOOcAThngCYAquBAvKmGAD5GmVqdBowAKtAJYBbCRgkA3PF179yVGvSYB5AEYArPAGMMyviTVDNjQrVoBDLAG5MbVYI0ib9rGHZFbDgA85u7CTKz4AHzO2Phu6mGMugbGvmAA3mAA1ADaAM4YksQA5gC6AFzxliIRBAC+Ma4hCVbi0rIKHGA6cHAweHbEKsQUUjp4tCoFRcUq8nASjM4ucQAidhh2AJKradMSJSsE65tp6cqLlSfbq6h16IZwxAVgWFcbdmdgl2AARACMACYAMy-MD3R7PDBgAAelWa1XCrj8TlQEigYAAFLE8HAMTDfOw-AByOD6IwYYlgABk1LAAEIvA4AHQSPJMrCYmEASm5GWUwGAYAAorY6GAABYTPAAGm+jG+eTAj3kdkkgxM3BhrIVfgArM46kA).

See https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/

Comment: I checked out your example, and I think there's a problem - there is an assignment of a number to `x.id`, which type system rightfully does not allow (flow displays an error). However, when I replace the number with a string (which is compstible with `DataID` type) - I get the same error.

Comment: That's correct, since `x` has type `AnySupportedObject` -- Flow does not know that it came from a variable with the `Data` type. Either you can allow mutation on `AnySupportedObject` or you can get covariant properties -- you cannot safely have both.

Comment: The types are not opaque. I want to really just do a type conversion there, anfter which the information that `y` can from type `Data` must be completely discarded. The reason why it doesn't work there is because there's still a reference to the same object at `x`. So it works if I use `const x: AnySupportedType = { ...y };` instead of diect assignment.

Comment: My brain is having difficulty processing this explanation, but the addition of the `+` sign magically fixed a similar JSON-like set of types that I had defined.